# how to make select box in react single selected and mulitple selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formio

I am using this package  to generate dynamic form
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-formio?activeTab=readme

As mentioned in the documentation to create `select box`

https://formio.github.io/formio.js/app/examples/select.html

I follow the steps but it is not working.It is not giving expected view output as mention in documentation. here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-smoke-07qyi

```
src={{
      display: "form",
      components: [
        {
          type: "select",
          label: "Single Select",
          key: "single",
          placeholder: "Select one",
          data: {
            values: [
              { value: "apple", label: "Apple" },
              { value: "banana", label: "Banana" },
              { value: "pear", label: "Pear" },
              { value: "orange", label: "Orange" }
            ]
          },
          dataSrc: "values",
          defaultValue: "banana",
          template: "<span>{{ item.label }}</span>",
          input: true
        }
      ]
    }}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-perlman-v3niz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a CSS issue to me.

Comment out the bootstrap import.

```
// import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Add the below code in `head` section on `public/index.html`

```
 <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/formiojs@latest/dist/formio.full.min.css"
    />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-perlman-v3niz

To fetch data from the server,

**Navigate to `Data tab` and select `Data Source Type` as `URL`.**

**Specify the `Data Source Url` and the `Data Path` (path to the array in response).**

In this case I'm using StarWars API.

https://swapi.co/api/people/

Which follows the below spec.

```
{
    "count": 87, 
    "next": "https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker", 
         }
     ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

The final code would look like below.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Form } from "react-formio";
import "./styles.css";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Form
    src={{
      display: "form",
      components: [
        {
          type: "select",
          label: "Single Select",
          key: "single",
          placeholder: "Select one",
          data: {
            values: [
              { value: "apple", label: "Apple" },
              { value: "banana", label: "Banana" },
              { value: "pear", label: "Pear" },
              { value: "orange", label: "Orange" }
            ]
          },
          dataSrc: "values",
          defaultValue: "banana",
          template: "<span>{{ item.label }}</span>",
          input: true
        },
        {
          label: "Select",
          mask: false,
          type: "select",
          input: true,
          key: "select2",
          defaultValue: "",
          data: {
            url: "https://swapi.co/api/people/",
            headers: [{ key: "", value: "" }],
            values: []
          },
          dataSrc: "url",
          template: "<span>{{ item.name }}</span>",
          selectValues: "results",
          disableLimit: false,
          searchField: "",
          clearOnRefresh: false,
          reference: false
        },
        {
          type: "button",
          label: "Submit",
          key: "submit",
          disableOnInvalid: true,
          theme: "primary",
          input: true
        }
      ]
    }}
    onSubmit={i => {
      console.log(i);
    }}
  />,

  // <Form src="https://peb3z.sse.codesandbox.io/abc" onSubmit={(i)=>{console.log(i)}} />,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: form where you get this css `.choices[data-type*="select-one"] .choices__input `

Comment: can I get this data from any service `like http:example.***` `{ value: "apple", label: "Apple" },
              { value: "banana", label: "Banana" },
              { value: "pear", label: "Pear" },`

Comment: can I fetch option data  from the server `` ?

Comment: You don't even need that. I was trying to tweak some css. The problem is version mismatch. You are using different version in formbuilder (2.1.1) and your app is using 4.* version. I reverted it to 2.1.1

Comment: Yes you can fetch from server too.

Comment: `Yes you can fetch from server too`how it would be great if  you provide me this info also using screen short as you did previouly

Comment: you can use this link to create select box which get data from server https://codesandbox.io/s/cra-react-formio-iy8lz . ..please share the step and screenshot that will be helpful

Comment: here is my service https://traumaticplaintiveoutliers--five-nine.repl.co/abc

Comment: could you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686378/how-to-listen-button-click-event-in-react