# how to listen button click event in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formio

I am using the package below to generate a form dynamically in react:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-formio

I found one example  where `on button click, an event is listening`
https://jsfiddle.net/Formio/obhgrrd8/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=obhgrrd8

I want to do same thing in `react` using the above package
here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-austin-vjdrj

I have three buttons I want to listen `button click event`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Form src="https://wzddkgsfhfvtlmv.form.io/parentform" />,

  // <Form src="https://peb3z.sse.codesandbox.io/abc" onSubmit={(i)=>{console.log(i)}} />,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: Maybe [custom event](https://github.com/formio/react-formio#event-props) or [action](https://github.com/formio/react-formio#event-props-4)

Comment: how . ?? can you share yourcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need to select an event as action from the button modal.

[image]

And give an event name(say **eventFromButton1**).

[image]

And in the `<Form />` component, add `onCustomEvent` prop.

```
<Form
        form={{
        onCustomEvent={customEvent => {
          console.log(customEvent);
        }}
 />
```

`onCustomEvent` function will receive a prop object with following structure

```
{
 type: "eventFromButton1",
 component: {},
 data: {}, 
 event: MouseEvent
}
```

You can use the `type` property to identify which button triggered the update, and use the `data` property to get the form data.

An attempt to modify the form data using a button added below (I don't see good documentation on these customizations in `react-formio`)

Uses `submission` data as react `state`.

Alter the state on `onCustomEvent` and re-render the form.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Form } from "react-formio";

    function CustomForm() {
      const [submission, setSubmission] = useState({});
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form
        form={{
          components: [
            {
              label: "First Name",
              validate: { required: true, minLength: 3 },
              key: "firstName",
              type: "textfield",
              input: true
            },
            {
              type: "textfield",
              key: "lastName",
              label: "Last Name",
              placeholder: "Enter your last name",
              input: true
            },
            {
              label: "Pupulate Nast Name",
              action: "event",
              showValidations: false,
              key: "submit1",
              type: "button",
              input: true,
              event: "someEvent"
            },
            {
              type: "button",
              label: "Submit",
              key: "submit",
              disableOnInvalid: true,
              input: true
            }
          ]
        }}
        submission={{ data: submission }}
        onSubmit={a => {
          console.log(a);
        }}
        onSubmitDone={a => {
          console.log(a);
        }}
        onCustomEvent={customEvent => {
          console.log(customEvent);
          setSubmission({ ...customEvent.data, lastName: "Laaast Name" });
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
 }

export default CustomForm;
```

There are some glitches in form though.

**You would see a flicker in UI.**

**Validation errors would be gone(Looks like submit button is still disabled though)**

Try this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-paper-x83us)

Also you can try using redux as mentioned in documentation.

Comment: what is use property `submission ` when it is called `submission={{ data: submission }} `

Comment: `onSubmit ` is called when button type `Submit ` is clicked correct ??

Comment: when `onSubmitDone ` is callled ?

Comment: It's the submission data of the form with format   `{data: {field1: value1, field2: value2}}` . I'm preserving the prev value and modifying a field on a custom button event. `onSubmitDone` is called only if a url prop is specified on `<Form />`. In the example I posted, it will not get called

Comment: `if a url prop is specified on <Form />` it means form is populated from any request correct ??

Comment: mean form it generated from url correct ??currently I am using hard corded `json` ?

Comment: it would be great if you answer last my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680278/how-to-reset-the-form-and-enable-submit-button-after-form-submision-react-formi

Comment: Yes, It should ideally be from formio url. In the code you posted, you are using it correctly..

Comment: it  would be great if you answer my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680278/how-to-reset-the-form-and-enable-submit-button-after-form-submision-react-formi

Comment: @Nihin any idea of above question

Comment: due to know any better library for building dynamic forms

Comment: Custom event is not getting triggered Is this syntax correct ? form={{
        onCustomEvent={customEvent => {
          console.log(customEvent);
        }}

Answer (score -2):

react at the end generates javascript code. So, you can use the events similar to javascript in react as well.

For example,

```
const submit = ()=>{
//your work goes here
}

return (
<div onClick={submit}> // or onClick={ ()=>submit()}

</div>
)
```

Comment: @vijay this is not a correct way ...!! please remove this answer