# how to reset the form and enable submit button after form submision (react-formio)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formio

I am using the [react-formio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-formio) package to generate a form dynamically.

I have generated a simple login-form using this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cra-react-formio-iy8lz

After building, it creates a JSON. Then, I generate a form using that JSON, but when I submit by form after `fulfill all validation of form` it always is shown in `disable mode` why?

How can we enable button again ?? when my `promise is resolved` and how to reset the form after submitting it?

here is my code, [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-surf-6vfhh)

```
onSubmit={i => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(i.data));
  var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout(function() {
        resolve("foo");
      }, 300);
   });
 }
```

[image]
one more thing

I also added `one more button`

```
{
   label: "Click",
   action: "event",
   showValidations: false,
   block: true,
   key: "click",
   type: "button",
   input: true,
   event: "clickEvent"
},
```

I also added click handler but it is not working

```
clickEvent={() => {
  alert("--ss");
}}
```

Comment: [Try this](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-almeida-2yqe8)

Comment: There is a glitch though, where you can see an error message(below submit button) on second submit, but the form actually gets submitted.

Comment: Also not that, these kind of customisation are not documented well. So I would suggest, if the library is not suitable for your requirements, you should consider not build on top of it. Please create a ticket on the GitHub repo of formio and see what the team responds.

Comment: i think glitch can be remove using `css` ..to overide css

Comment: It can be. But in future you might face issues that might be hard to debug. Also they have a react starter kit which shows the customisation that can be done. You can download it and play around in your local machine

Comment: @NithinThampi that I think that  needs `sign up` of their website need to create project there

Comment: No. Just clone this repo and run in local machine https://github.com/formio/react-app-starterkit

Comment: thanks for help ...!! last what is meaning of these two lines 

    .If you have not already, create a project on https://portal.form.io. You can import the src/project.json file to add all the forms and resources needed for this project.

    Modify the src/config.js file to point the PROJECT_URL variable to the project you created in form.io.

Comment: what I understand that `play with src/project.json` ?? can change the `PROJECT_URL` .`PROJECT_URL` will be `path of project.json file` correct ?

Comment: I'm on phone. So can't confirm it. But..The app uses  a default form configuration. You can refer the network tab to see the form json . You can create your own form with your account and replace the default urls to return custom form json.

Comment: You are welcome brother. I'll reply to the comment tom evening if you are facing any difficulties.

Comment: as suggested I download the project and  do `npm install` and run project ..!! nothing see ..`(only home page with have login button on header  see attached image`)https://filebin.net/uve3ccvdx19unq4h/Screenshot_2019-11-05_at_4.53.58_AM.png?t=sakuiu9t I didn't create a account on their website` .

Comment: I didn't sign up on their website .move `project.json` on public folder (`same level of index.html`).change `var PROJECT_URL = '/project.json';
var API_URL = 'https://api.form.io';
`  on config file .but nothing show

Comment: could you please help how to start this project ???

Comment: It would be great if you told me what are step you take after `npm i` and npm start

Comment: Launch the application -> Click on register instead of login(It should be a dummy register function) -> You should see a link `events` next to home button ->  Click there to see the form -> Go to code base and see the how the form is created (Use the routes to see the form component being rendered)

Comment: Thanks..!! helpful

Comment: @NithinThampi due to know any better library for building dynamic forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the **submission** property of the `<Form />` component.

As per docs..

> Submission data to fill the form. You can either load a previous
>   submission or create a submission with some pre-filled data. If you do
>   not provide a submissions the form will initialize an empty submission
>   using default values from the form.

So in this case you can control the  component in a parent component.

Here `submissionData` is a parent component state and the  component initializes with the state from parent (Empty values initially).

```
<Form submission={{ data: submissionData }} />
```

Now, inside the `onSubmit` handler you can try to reset the state and force a re-render.

```
    onSubmit={() => {
         // Reset submission data
          setSubmissionData({});
        };
      }
```

Complete code would look like below.

```
export default () => {
  const [submissionData, setSubmissionData] = useState({});
  return (
    <Form
      //all form props
      submission={{ data: submissionData }}
      onSubmit={() => {
        var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            resolve("foo");
          }, 300);
        });

        promise1.then(function(value) {
          alert(value);
         // Reset submission data
          setSubmissionData({});
        });
      }}
    />
  }
```

Attached  codesandbox link as comment.

Comment: i think using css we can remove glitches

Comment: You can do it. But make sure you don't too much over the board customisations. You won't get too much helpe if you do that because nobody would have experience in doing these many customisations. And you might not get enough help

Comment: @NithinThampi due to know any better library for building dynamic forms

Comment: @NithinThampi Can you pls let me know which data variable contain the json data in this example.
is submissionData will be responsible for collecting the json data or any other varible ? as I want to save this Json data into my own database.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a reference to the FormIO form and then used it to get to the underlying `formio` object to `emit` a `resetForm` event.

This is the code for the reference:

```js
// The reference
const formComponent = useRef()
```

```js
// The submit handler
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  formIOContainer.current.innerHTML = '';
  // This is the code which resets the form
  const current = formComponent.current
  current.formio.emit('resetForm')
}

// The Form IO form with the on submit event handler
return (
  <>
    <div id="formIOContainerScroller"/>
    <div id="formIOContainer" ref={formIOContainer}/>
    <Form src={targetUrl}
          onFormLoad={onFormLoad}
          options={formOptions}
          onSubmitDone={onSubmitDone}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          ref={formComponent}
    />
  </>
)
```

This code resets the form after submission and the button is enabled after submission. So you can submit multiple times. Every time you submit the form gets reset.